# What is different between @+id/android:list and @id/android:list?

Tags: android, syntax

I've develop android application, and one question.

As you know, When we use LiveActivity, we must specify @id/android:list for ListView ID.

But, When I use @+id/android:list instead of @id/android:list, it is working fine.

What is different between @+id/android:list and @id/android:list ??

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental difference between `@` and `@+` is that `@+` is signaling that you need to add a new id, the `@` by itself tells the compiler to look for an existing id.

Comment: Also the R.xxx generator looks for @+id afaik. It's a bit of wacky naming system if you've used XAML

Answer (score 4):

> As you know, When we use LiveActivity,
>   we must specify @id/android:list for
>   ListView ID.

No, you do not. [You must specify `@android:id/list` for the `ListView` ID for use with `ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

> But, When I use @+id/android:list
>   instead of @id/android:list, it is
>   working fine.

No, those will give you compile errors. Colons are not valid characters in Java field names, and so those IDs are illegal.

Switching back to legal Android syntax, if you are declaring your own ID (no `android:` in the value), the first time you use the ID in a file, you are supposed to have the `+` sign. The second and subsequent times, the `+` sign is not needed, though it seems to cause no harm if you have in there as well.

Comment: But, I've found reference for ListActivity in Android Developers. and you can see @id/android:list in sample code if you click below link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

sample code:

...
     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
...
     <TextView id="@id/android:empty"
...            

If you use @+id/android:id instread of @id/android:id, then you can see same result. Just test it ;)

Comment: @CommonsWare When determining what is "the first time you use the ID in a file", do includes get inlined / counted or not?

Comment: @sschuberth: Good question. I am not really certain, as I do not use `<include>` all that much.

Answer (score 1):

In response to [What is different between @+id/android:list and @id/android:list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264235/what-is-different-between-id-androidlist-and-id-androidlist/3264532#3264532):

It seems that there are two ways to reference to the platform id `android.R.id.list`: `@android:id/list` and `@id/android:list`. The ListActivity documentation shows both (the first one in text, second in the example) but does not clarify if there's any difference.

The `@+id/android:list` as the ListView's id seems to work too. I assume that what happens here is that a copy of the `android.R.id.list` identifier is added to the application's own ID list.

In my opinion `@android:id/list` is the clearest way for referencing to `android.R.id.list`.

Answer (score 1):

**Resource IDs** in Android are specific to a package (which is good, or else you'd have lots of conflicts if your app is dealing with several packages at the same time).

**`@+id/list`** will create a resource ID in your `app (=your package)` with the name **`"list"`** and give it a unique ID. In code, that would be *`R.id.list`*.

**`@android:id/list`** will use the ID **`"list"`** from the package android (which, in code, would be *`android.R.id.list`*.