# RelativeLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have this XMl in my main...

> 

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="4px" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/search"
        layout="@layout/search" />



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wordList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my problem is that my ListView doesn't appears android:id="@+id/search" below... so what I do wrong ?

Comment: can you provide search layout code.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
android:layout_below="@id/search"
```

The `+` is not needed there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731414/what-is-the-difference-betwenn-id-and-id-in-android

Comment: In fact, not only is it not needed, but it is required to be absent.

Comment: but I want to know which case I have to use '+' ?

Comment: you should use + when you want to create new id

Comment: yes, means when you are adding a view, link in first comment have good description for same......

Answer (score 0):

Another assumption: The included layout may have height="match_parent" so that the ListView doesnt have any space left...