# What is the accepted practice for @id vs. @+id usage in Android development?

Tags: android, android-studio, standards

I am new to Android development.

I noticed that sometimes `@+id` was used instead of `@id`. From what I could find, apparently when you compile a program, it first scans the source data and the `@+id` tells it to add the id to the R file, and then after that it is considered okay to use `@id`.

Is there a good practice to use for this? Could I theoretically always use `@+id` to be safe? What about using `@+id` once to add it to R, and then removing the plus sign now that it's already present?

Or is there an accepted practice of where the `@+id` version is to be declared if `@id` is to be used everywhere else?

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160954/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id)

Comment: @JoeMaher I understand that (which is why I mentioned this in the OP) -- I am asking about practices

Comment: Do you want any example ?

Comment: I just generally follow the terms that if you are assigning an id to a view use @+id, when referring to a view use @id

Comment: Check [here](http://android-wtf.com/2012/11/difference-between-at-plus-id-and-at-id-in-android/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5731533/1435985) for answers. Both give reasons why you might not want to always uses @+id on everything.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan So if I am always using `@+id` then there is a risk that when I typo something, it'll think I'm creating a new label instead of trying to reference a pre-existing one, and compile without error (whereas I'd really want it to error out and tell me I typoed something)

Comment: Correct. You can try it yourself real fast by trying to reference a resource you haven't given an id to. You will get an error stating a resource was not found with the given name. If you add the `+` the application will compile and only give an error in the file.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Is it considered bad practice to mess with R.java?

Comment: I would certainly say so. It is an auto generated file and I have never come across a reason to edit it myself. Can't say the same for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think generally if you are assigning an id to a view `@+id`, referring to a view `@id`

```
<Button 
   android:id="@+id/start"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<Button 
   android:id="@+id/check"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/start"
/>
```

Comment: So basically use `@+id` when assigning something to android:id (since presumably this is the first time it's being used). Is there any downside to me just adding something to R.java directly and then never using `@+id`?

Comment: I tend to try and stay away from touching auto generated files, but each to their own

Answer (score 2):

@+id is used at the first occurrence of that `id` . This of course implies that whenever we are assigning an id the `@+id` is used. Besides this practice, whenever we are referring to an id for first time, eg in `RelativeLayout` if we use `above` for a particular id, and we assign that id to an element (`Button` or `TextView`) below that line of code, we have to use `...above="@+id/not_yet_assigned"` 
For example:

```
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_first"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_second"
        android:text="ONE"
        />
       <Button
        android:id="@id/btn_second"
        android:text="TWO"
        />
```