# No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, xml, resources

Here is my (relevant) XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="myOnClickMethod"
        android:layout_below="@id/whiteBackground" <---- ERROR HERE
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/whiteBackground"  <---- HERE IS THE ID
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/white_background"
        android:tag="white"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/myrect"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_text_editor"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/text_size_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/size"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:onClick="SizeChange"
        android:layout_below="@id/whiteBackground" <---- ALSO BEING USED HERE (NO ERROR)
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/menu_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/whiteBackground"  <----ALSO BEING USED HERE (NO ERROR)
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="MoveChange"
        android:text="MOVE"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm getting an error on the noted line above.  It's telling me

`No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_below' with value '@id/whiteBackground').`

I'm not sure why this is happening because as you can see the ID/element is sitting right below it where noted.  And as you can see the other 2 buttons below that also use the same `layout_below="@id/whiteBackground"` and there are no errors there.  It's just the 1 line.

If someone could tell me what's going on, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try `@+id` the first time you reference it (reading top to bottom), and `@id` every time after that.

Comment: Thank you so much @stkent i guess that's just something that happens with relativelayouts

Comment: It happens more commonly with `RelativeLayout`s, yes, but it's not unique to them!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731533/2911458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
layout_below="@id/whiteBackground"
```

to

```
layout_below="@+id/whiteBackground"
```

I hope it will hope you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/menu_button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/whiteBackground"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:onClick="myOnClickMethod" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/whiteBackground"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_text_editor"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect"
    android:contentDescription="@string/white_background"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    android:tag="white"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/text_size_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/whiteBackground"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/menu_button"
    android:onClick="SizeChange"
    android:text="@string/size"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/move_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/whiteBackground"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_button"
    android:onClick="MoveChange"
    android:text="MOVE" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

- Add height and width in the root of the xml code .

  ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
  ```
- make sure that the id is existed .

  ```
   android:layout_below="@+id/image_text_editor"
  ```